# Passing the byte stream from an application to console app using StandardInput?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I'm trying to invoke the exe app using the Process method, I need to pass the pdf byte stream. While using the StandardInput, I'm trying something like this:

```cs
var stream = myexe.StandardInput;
try
{
    stream.Write(content);
}

finally
{
    stream.Close();
}
```

On the other end, I'm trying to read this:

```cs
var bytesInStream = new byte[10*1024];
var input = Console.OpenStandardInput();
var temp = input.Read(bytesInStream, 0, (int)bytesInStream.Length);
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: `Process.StandardInput` is a StreamWriter, which uses an encoding to convert data to binary. You don't want that in this case. Try using `Process.StandardInput.BaseStream.Write(pdf, 0, pdf.Length)`.

Comment: `input.Read` only reads a single buffer. You can use `Stream.CopyTo`to copy the incoming bytes to a MemoryStream or FileStream. You should use use `OpenStandardInpu()` or `StandardInput.BaseStream` to get the process's input stream instead of the StreamWriter

Comment: Also note that you will need a way to let the child process know when it has read the correct number of bytes. One way to do this is to close the stream once you've written all the data, which will cause the child process to hit the End Of File condition once it's read all the data. Another way is to prepend a bit of meta-data to the stream that tells the child process how many bytes to read.

Comment: StdIn is a text stream, specifically not suitable for PDF (a binary format).  Use a file instead.

Comment: @Hans, that's why it was suggested to use `OpenStandardInput()` or `StandardInput.BaseStream`. It definitely works just fine with binary data.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at `StandardInput` method under Process class, it returns StreamWriter.
If you use `stream.Write(object")`. It actually writes the string values which you can read at other end.
For the byte array pdf stream, you need to use

```
stream.BaseStream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
```

and on the other end read it like this:

```
` var input = Console.OpenStandardInput();
  var temp = input.Read(bytesInStream, 0, (int)bytesInStream.Length);`
```

you can also send the byte stream length as args, if not sure about the size.